# Select only numerics or integers

Tags: r, dplyr

I wanted to select only those columns which are integer and numeric data types with `dplyr`.

There is a post about selecting columns that are numeric data type

```
dat <- dplyr::select_if(dat, is.numeric)
```

I was wondering if I could use something similar that can select columns that are numeric and integer both:

```
dat <- dplyr::select_if(dat, is.numeric && is.integer)

or

dat <- dplyr::select_if(dat, c(is.numeric, is.integer))
```

Although both above seem not be working.

Comment: Integers are also numeric, e.g. `class(1:10); is.numeric(1:10)`, so `select_if(dat, is.numeric)` should be sufficient. If you want e.g. all numeric and character columns, you could do `select_if(dat, ~is.numeric(.x) | is.character(.x))`

Comment: @JorisChau - I was working on FlexDashBoard and I noticed that columns are picked which are numeric but integer cols were not picked in one of the coded where I wanted both the cols to be picked up.

Comment: Although `integers` are `numeric`s, sometimes, it's important to select integers so is.integer alone is sufficient.

Comment: @NelsonGon: but only `is.integer` will not select the non-integer numeric columns?

Comment: Yes @JorisChau but if one is interested in non-integer columns too, then using `is.integer` is pointless. `is.numeric` is sufficient as you stated.

Comment: @NelsonGon - I was wondering, if we omit any character type vars, then we can get a df that contains vars such as integer, numeric, factor etc. Right?

Answer (score 3):

A variable that is both integer and numeric is integer (every integer is also a numeric). So either you use is.numeric to catch all integers and reals or you use as.integer to catch only the integer ones.

If you're not too attached to using dplyr, this will do (using is.numeric here).

```
dat_selected <- dat[sapply(dat, is.numeric)]
```

Comment: Just use `Filter(is.numeric, df)`.